# Calculating probability of getting a college based on general acceptance rate and class profile statistics

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If I apply to one college with a 25% chance of being accepted and 40% of the student body is female and 20% of the student body is Asian, what is the probability of acceptance for an Asian female to be accepted to this college?

I believe these events are all independent of each other, so would the probability = (.25)x(.4)x(.2) = 2% or is the probability = (1-.25)x(1-.4)x(1-.2) = 36%?  Or do I need to use conditional probabilities? Or am I totally off the path here?

Any guidance would help out tremendously and would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There is not enough information.  Perhaps the college accepts every Asian woman that applies, perhaps the college accepts  no Asian women at all.  There is no way to tell.

Comment: What additional information would be needed?

Comment: Not sure there's any obvious set of data that would do the job.  Well, you could be told the probability for an Asian female, but of course that would be circular.